# angular.forEach() not working

Tags: angularjs, service, foreach

Hi friend I'm beginner in angular and getting stuck by using `angular.forEach()` function. I just want to call data from a nested array in `data.json` file. Please check my code below... `****I want to call data from --users-- key****`

**HTML**

```
<div class="user-container" ng-controller="users">
        <ul class="list">
            <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in items">
                {{key}} <p> {{value}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**Problems with current code**

> When run my code in browser Its giving me only 2 `<li>` in `ng-repeat` then in {{Key}} I'm getting `0` in first `<li>` and `1` in second `<li>`
>
> and in {{value}} I'm getting whole user list in first `<li>` and in second `<li>` their is no data

**data.json**

```
{
    "data": {
        "new": true,
        "show_page": false,
        "status": "signedin",
        "users": [{
            "Michele": {
                "logo": "xyz.jpg",
                "status": "active",
                "active_since": 2015,
                "order": 1
            },
            "Gerry": {
                "logo": "xyz.jpg",
                "status": "active",
                "active_since": 2015,
                "order": 1
            }
}]
    },
    "success": true
}
```

**Controller.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', []);

myApp.service('userData', ['$http', function($http){
  return{
    userslist : function(){
        return $http({'url' : 'data.json', 'method' : 'GET'}).then(function(response){
        return response.data;
      }, function(data){
        console.log(data)
      })
    }
  }
}]);

myApp.controller('users', ['$scope', '$http', 'userData', function($scope, $http, userData){
  userData.userslist().then(function(data){
    //var provideDataKey = Object.keys(data.users)[0];
    $scope.items = [];
    angular.forEach(data, function(item){
                   //console.log(item.users);
                   $scope.items.push(item.users)
               })
    console.log($scope.items)
  })
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response` is the HTTP response, with its body (data), headers, etc.

So `response.data` is the body, which looks like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "new": true,
        "show_page": false,
        "status": "signedin",
        "users": [{
            "Michele": {
                "logo": "xyz.jpg",
                "status": "active",
                "active_since": 2015,
                "order": 1
            },
            "Gerry": {
                "logo": "xyz.jpg",
                "status": "active",
                "active_since": 2015,
                "order": 1
            }
        }]
    },
    "success": true
}
```

What you want is to access the `users` field of the `data` field of this body. So what you want is

```
userData.userslist().then(function(data){
    $scope.items = data.data.users;
    console.log($scope.items)
})
```

$scope. items is an array, not an object. You want to display the elements of this array. So the syntax is:

{{ user }}

Your JSON is awful, because each user is an object with a single field, and you have no way of knowing the name of that field. You'd better change it to

```
 "users": [
    {
         "name": "Michele",
         "logo": "xyz.jpg",
         "status": "active",
         "active_since": 2015,
         "order": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Gerry",
        "logo": "xyz.jpg",
        "status": "active",
        "active_since": 2015,
        "order": 1
    }
]
```

That way you could just do:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in items">
   {{ user.name }}, active since {{ user.active_since }}.
```

Comment: Thanks for help.. :)

Comment: Then post-process the JSON in the controller to produce structure similar to the one suggested in the answer, so that the view can display users easily.

Comment: thing is I cant change the structure bcz its a api calling from server..

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
myApp.controller('users', ['$scope', '$http', 'userData', function($scope, $http, userData){
  userData.userslist().then(function(data){
    //var provideDataKey = Object.keys(data.users)[0];
    $scope.items = [];
    angular.forEach(data.users[0], function(item){
                   $scope.items.push(item);
               })
    console.log($scope.items)
  })
}]);
```

you were iterating over data and not on users.

Comment: thanks for help.. but as per your suggestion I'm getting `[]` empty in console